# argument list for class template Vec2 is missing

Tags: c++, arguments, friend

I am defining a Vec2 class with a friend functions.   I am getting the error:  argument list for class template Vec2 is missing for the friend function: friend Vec2 operator * (const T &r, const Vec2 &v).

```
    template<typename T>
    class Vec2
    {
    public:
        Vec2() : x(0), y(0) {}
        Vec2(T xx) : x(xx), y(xx) {}
        Vec2(T xx, T yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
        Vec2 operator + (const Vec2 &v) const
        { return Vec2(x + v.x, y + v.y); }
        Vec2 operator / (const T &r) const
        { return Vec2(x / r, y / r); }
        Vec2 operator * (const T &r) const
        { return Vec2(x * r, y * r); }
        Vec2& operator /= (const T &r)
        { x /= r, y /= r; return *this; }
        Vec2& operator *= (const T &r)
        { x *= r, y *= r; return *this; }
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &s, const Vec2<T> &v)
        {
            return s << '[' << v.x << ' ' << v.y << ']';
        }
        friend Vec2 operator * (const T &r, const Vec2<T> &v)
        {   return Vec2(v.x * r, v.y * r); }
        T x, y;
    };
```

Comment: your code compiles fine with gcc 5. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (code compiles fine with g++ 4.9.2 and -Wall).  Even if I try `Vec2<double> v2; 1.0*v2;`.  Could you provide a `main()` that triggers the error?

Comment: [OT] You should implement your free and member `operator*` in terms of your `operator*=` to avoid unnecessary code duplication.

Comment: I tried it with VS 2010 and it fails.  Not sure if I need to set up some flags in the compiler

Comment: It is possible VS 2010 is more picky when it comes to uses of the injected class name.  Try replacing plain `Vec2` by `Vec2<T>` in the declaration and the definition of `operator*`.

Comment: Found issue VS2010 does not support all the options in c++11.  Used g++ and worked fine.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: For future searchers: [Support Matrix For C++11/14/17 Features in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh567368.aspx)